# Installed the Arc Theme, it doesn't look right

Tags: unity, themes, gtk, gtk3, appearance

I just installed the [Arc Theme](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme), however it doesn't look right. As you can see here, mine looks completely different and looks like it's missing textures and other things:

[image]

Whereas the normal theme looks like this:

[image]

My icons aren't changing either.

I'm activating it from the Unity Tweak Tool, and I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: There is a suggested workaround here: https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme/issues/185#issuecomment-141105437.

Comment: @mightyspaj, Naheel's answer works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue.

> This theme doesn't support Ubuntu 14.04, because its GTK version (3.10) is too old. I'm working on GTK 3.14 support, which will make the theme compatible with Ubuntu 15.04.
>   I'm sorry about this, but I don't have enough resources to backport the theme to older GTK versions.

Source: https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme/issues/7

---

### Workaround

Depending on which Arc theme you are using, edit the corresponding `.css` file. Even better, edit all of them and fix all Arc themes on 14.04:

- Arc: `sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Arc/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`
- Arc Dark: `sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`
- Arc Darker: `sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Arc-Darker/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Once gedit opens press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and type the word `dashed`

Now simply replace the highlighted word `dashed` with the word `none`

i.e. change this line: `outline-style: dashed;` to this: `outline-style: none;`

Save, close, and you're done. Enjoy.

Comment: :( That sucks. I wanted to use it

Comment: Welcome to magic the world of GTK 3, where theming APIs are broken at each minor release.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

on line 26 comment it to be like this

```
/*outline-style: dashed;*/
```

save and enjoy